# Solaris 11 seems to be missing system header files

Tags: solaris, sunstudio

I've installed Solaris 11 x86 (in a qemu environment) from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html

I've untar'd into /opt Sun Studio 12.3 x86 for Solaris 11 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html

but the compiler can't find system headers like sys/types.h or inttypes.h or anywhere which may define int32_t. The dtrace.h header for example relies on sys/types.h, and I can't find it. As if I'm missing a package or something. I've never worked with anything other than Linux (many distros, including from source), and I'm lost. What am I missing?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for www.serverfault.com

Comment: @cillosis: I'm a developer. I'm trying to make my source code build on this exotic toolchain and platform, not administer a server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to install the package containing these header files:

```
# pkg install system/header
```

Comment: Where should I have RTFM'd this? What else is missing in the default install?

Comment: Studio 12.3 documentation predates Solaris 11 and hasn't this information documented. The issue is you installed from a tar file so there is no dependency checking. Should you have installed from the recently released solarisstudio publisher, I guess these header files would have been automatically installed.

Comment: Also need to install these if using gcc from the opencsw project - I could not find this documented anywhere